How to add GDPR accept privacy checkbox before submiting posts and topics on forum
I decided to open a WooCommerce web shop on WordPress, because I already have shop in real life I manage to connected everything and after few months of struggle and watching hundreds of tutorials I achieve to get everything on my site that I was looking for (backend is on 95% and front-end is on 70% finished - but I will finish it soon because only easy part left)
I am from Croatia and my site is for Croatians, because Croatia is in Europe website must follow GDPR, I manage to get everything done (cookie banner, cookie info, privacy policy, contact, delete accounts.. checkboxes of consent... and all other things), but now I'm stuck with one issue that I can't solve. I'm using Asgaros FREE plugin/addon for forum, but there is no checkbox for user to accept privacy (GDPR consent) before submitting posts. Can anyone help me with code how to add checkbox that is required before users submits post on Asgaros forum.
I used snipped code (PHP) to add a checkbox on WooCommerce registration, and it's working, but I don't know how to achieve that on the forum.
Code that I used for registration that is working:
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wtwh_add_registration_privacy_policy', 11 );
function wtwh_add_registration_privacy_policy() {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy_reg', array(
       'type'          => 'checkbox',
       'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
       'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
       'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
       'required'      => true,
       'label'         => 'I\'ve read rules and i accept <a href="/privacy-policy">privacy policy</a>',
    ));
}
  
// Show error if user does not tick
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'wtwh_validate_privacy_registration', 10, 3 );  
function wtwh_validate_privacy_registration( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['privacy_policy_reg'] ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'privacy_policy_reg_error', __( 'Please read our privacy policy and accept terms!', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

That worked for register, but can't find way how to add checkbox like that on Asgaros forum (before submitting post or topic)
I would REALLY appreciate if anyone can help me. I am really trying to make my site fully GDPR compliant and I manage to do all steps except this one, this is last thing that's left to do.
Here is list of all Asgaros hooks (Actions & Filters)
https://github.com/Asgaros/asgaros-forum/blob/master/hooks.md
I tried experimenting for days to get it done, tried many different PHP codes, even tried code that ChatGPT4 gave me, but neither one worked. So I decided to do backup (just in case) and then I joined Stack Overflow to ask for help. I'm hoping someone will be able to help me. I will reward first one who provide me PHP code that is going to help me to solve the issue. I really need your help.

Do you need to store the user answer for the GDPR checkbox? If not, you can add a checkbox with GDPR directly into HTML and check it on the frontend or backend side. It will be easier, but it also has a downside of such solutions - after you update the plugin or WordPress this can stop working.

See: Asgaros: gdpr and Asgaros: Consent Boxes (GDPR)… So is better to search and ask directly in Asgaros Support pages first.
